# pgAdmin failed to save password for users

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have pgAdmin (`dpage/pgadmin4:4.29`) container running in Kubernetes. As a master user I have added Database connections and share the connection. I can disconnect/reconnect to database without password as a master user.

But for additional users I have created, those users password are not getting saved even they have selected **Save Password** option at the time of connection. pgAdmin keep asking for password when connecting to DB.

What I am missing in my setup.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I set a Master Password but the Save Password checkbox can't be checked.

Answer (score 5):

NobleUplift's issue of the "Save Password" checkbox being disabled can be caused by certain config flags in the config.py file. Remembering passwords for SSH tunneling is disabled by default, for example.

You can re-enable the checkbox by writing

```
ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD = True  # SSH tunnel password saving, default False
ALLOW_SAVE_PASSWORD = True         # database password saving, default True
```

to a new `config_local.py` file in the same directory where you find your main `config.py` file. Pg discourages writing the the main `config.py` file directly. See [the docs](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html#config-py) for more details about the preferred config file and where to find them. (I found mine under "`pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py`", not where the docs said.)

[This](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxoy87kYcx0sP_ijLbxpKnQxDuAc8GSgTFCipJ33F73bgqw@mail.gmail.com) seems to be where the 'disable password saving' idea came from.

Apologies roy for not answering your question directly, but I didn't have the ability to respond directly to Noble. However, the [config docs](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html#config-py) also mention that the `ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION` flag can interfere with Kubernetes (and other auth settings), which might be worth a look.